# How to increment a numerical value in properties file

Tags: bash, shell

I have a `version.properties` file as below:

```
#some comments
major=2
minor=16
patch=4
```

I want to increase the minor value by 1. so new value should be 16 +1 = 17.
So the updated file will be:

```
#some comments
major=2
minor=17
patch=4
```

Is it possible to achieve this through bash script?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use awk:

```
awk -F"=" 'BEGIN{OFS=FS} $1=="minor"{$2=$2+1}1' versions.properties
```

This `awk` script says:

1. Split each record by a an equal sign (`-F"="`)
2. Ensure that the output field separator `OFS` is equal to the incoming field separator `FS` (`BEGIN{OFS=FS}`)
3. If the first field is the word "minor"  (`$1=="minor"`)
4. Then add 1 to the second field (`{$2=$2+1}`)
5. Finally print the record back out `1`.

You can redirect this to a temp file and then mv the temp back over the top of the original:

```
 awk -F"=" 'BEGIN{OFS=FS} $1=="minor"{$2=$2+1}1' versions.properties > versions.properties.tmp && mv versions.properties.tmp versions.properties
```

Comment: Great. This is incrementing the minor version as required. However, the command is only printing the updated things in the console. Whereas I want to update the file.

Comment: Added the redirect to a temp file and `mv` command to overwrite the original to the bottom of the question

Comment: I think you mean this: awk -F"=" 'BEGIN{OFS=FS} $1=="minor"{$2=$2+1}1' versions.properties > versions.properties.tmp && mv versions.properties.tmp versions.properties

Comment: as there is no tmp file to start with, First awk will operate with original file and write the output to tmp file, then lastly mv will do the rest. Am i right?

Comment: @Coder Holy smokes yea...! Thanks for that. I have updated.

Comment: Can this be easily modified to work with decimals as well?  In my format, I have num=1.2 and lets say I want to increment by 0.1 every time, so next would be 1.3.

Comment: @ctrlbrk You could do `-F"[=.]"` which will split each line by both equal and dot. You'll have to change around `$2` to point to which ever field/column number contains your major/minor version you want to change.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use this:

```
#! /bin/bash
LINE=$(cat version.properties | grep minor)
VAL=$(echo $LINE | cut -f 2 -d "=")
VAL=$(($VAL + 1))
NEW_LINE=$(echo minor=$VAL)
sed -e "s,$LINE,$NEW_LINE,g" -i version.properties
```

It fixes the issue without the need to use additional redirections and mv commands. Hope this helps :-)

Answer (score 1):

**Steps:**

1- Get line number of your parameter (to use in replacement)

```
grep -n "minor" version.properties | cut -d: -f1
```

This shows "3" according to your version.properties file

We save it in a variable

```
line=$(grep -n "minor" version.properties | cut -d: -f1)
```

2- Get key=value

```
grep -n "minor" version.properties | cut -d: -f2
```

This shows minor=16 according to your version.properties file

We save it in a variable called **string**:

```
string=$(grep -n "minor" version.properties | cut -d: -f2)
```

3- Get version of this string : minor=**16**

```
version=$(echo $string | cut -d= -f2)
```

4- Increase version

```
newVersion=$(( version + 1))
```

5- Replace in original properties file using line number:

```
sed -i "$line c $key=$newVersion" version.properties
```

---

Finally this is a complete script , with key and file as parameters, so you could use it to increase any key like in any properties file, in any location :

```
key=$1
file=$2

line=$(grep -n "$key" $file | cut -d: -f1)
string=$(grep -n "$key" $file | cut -d: -f2)

# get version from string
version=$(echo $string | cut -d= -f2)

#increase version
newVersion=$(( version + 1))

#update file
sed -i "$line c $key=$newVersion" $file
```

**Usage:**

```
bash update_version.sh "patch" /server/files/version.properties
```

Note : keys in file must be unique.